# RecyclerView - a single selection selects every 10 row

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick, android-recyclerview

It's strange but when I long click on one row using my code, the star on that row turns gold (which is what I want), but also each star ten rows apart.
This is my code:

```
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView localeDisplay;
    private static final int grey_blue = 0xff546E7A;
    private static final int gold = 0xffffa000;

    public MyViewHolder(final View view) {
        super(view);
        localeDisplay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.languageText);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        Languages currentLanguages = languagesList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                                        Snackbar snackbar;
                                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, currentLanguages.getLocaleDisplay() + " selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                                                .setAction("Next", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                        View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
                                        snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(grey_blue);
                                        snackbar.show();
                                    }
                                }

        );

        view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()

                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Position is " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            ImageView star = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                                            if (star.getColorFilter() == null) {
                                                star.setColorFilter(gold);
                                            } else star.clearColorFilter();

                                            return true;
                                        }
                                    }

        );
    }
```

I have tried following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am7LgHCdZvI) but the same behavior happens.
Any ideas what I could do to correct this?

Comment: The view is being recycled, which means that it will be reused instead of recreated. If you set the star in one, when it is reused the start will still be set. You need a flag for each item individually to determine if it should or shouldn't have its star set. `set` meaning turning it gold.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but is this possible for a list that changes dynamically? If so, I'll try to work out how to do it.

Comment: You will just need a way of flagging each specific item in the list as clicked or not. For example, if you set item 9 in your list, you need something that says that item 9 is clicked. There are a large number of ways to approach this. The adapter just recognizes its is a view that can be used for what you want to do. It doesn't care what the current state of the view is.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your view is being recycled, what means your listener reference is being called to all recycled views.

An easy way to solve this is setting new references for each single view at onBindViewHolder method. Usually Viewholder is used to find views and keep the references for recycled views, isn't a good idea set data inside it.

You could change the viewholder for:

```
public ExampleViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        myContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.myContainer);
        localeDisplay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.languageText);
        star = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
```

And set the listener at onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    ExampleHolder holder = (ExampleHolder) viewHolder;

    //Insert the position reference
    holder.myContainer.setTag(position);

    // Setting listeners
    holder.myContainer.setOnClickListener(this);
    holder.myContainer.setOnLongClickListener(this); 

}
```

Then implement the OnLongClickListener and OnClickListener at your adapter.

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

    //Getting position
    int position = (int)v.getTag();

    //Insert your code
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //code here
}
```

Drop me a line back if works. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I am struggling a bit to get it to work but I will try again soon. :)

Comment: The problem is that I have View myView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view); but "view" cannot be resolved. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Try to reference layout container instead. (e.g. LinearLayout myContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.myContainer);) Don't forget to set listeners reference to myContainer.

Comment: I edited the answer with comment above and also how to insert and get the position reference.

Comment: Cheers! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad that helped you!

Answer (score 1):

in your adapter constructor, just add this part:

```
setHasStableIds(true).
```

and after that override the following methods in the adapter class.

```
 @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
   }

 @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     return position;
  }
```

Comment: adapter.setHasStableIds(true); (in your activity/fragment before rv.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are getting all items that have the `R.id.imageView` id. To do what you want, you need to grab the item that was clicked and change the color of the selected line only;

Comment: Thanks a lot but I don't think this is the case. ;-)